# How to retrieve Excel file inside project folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

With following codes I am able to copy **Book1.xlsx** file from **Application folder** to **Desktop**.

vb.net version

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName:=IO.Path.Combine(New IO.FileInfo(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName).DirectoryName, "Book1.xlsx"),
                 destFileName:=My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\Book1.xlsx")
End sub
```

C# version

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName: System.IO.Path.Combine(new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName).DirectoryName, "Book1.xlsx"), 
                          destFileName: My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop + @"\Book1.xlsx");
}
```

Please put **Book2.xlsx** file to the **Project Folder** by following this way: **Add > Existing Item**

How can I copy **Book2.xlsx** file from **Project Folder** and paste to desktop?

***Summary of my question is here:***

I am able to copy **Book1.xlsx** file from **Application folder** to **Desktop**.

How can I copy **Book2.xlsx** file from **Project folder** to **Desktop**.

Comment: This is not winforms code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please put Book2.xlsx file to the Project Folder by following this
>   way: Add > Existing Item
>
> How can I copy Book2.xlsx file from Project Folder and paste to
>   desktop?
>
> Summary of my question is here:
>
> I am able to copy Book1.xlsx file from Application folder to Desktop.
>
> How can I copy Book2.xlsx file from Project folder to Desktop.

In WPF, you need to use [the Pack URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf) to access the file which you did as **' put Book2.xlsx file to the Project Folder by following this way: Add > Existing Item'**

And set the Book2.xlsx **Build Action as 'Resource'**.  Then, try the following code.

```
      private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string excelPath = "pack://application:,,,/Xbook2.xlsx";
        StreamResourceInfo excelInfo = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(excelPath));

        using (Stream file = File.Create(@"D:\Xbook2.xlsx"))
        {
            CopyStream(excelInfo.Stream, file);
        }

        //System.IO.File.Copy(excelInfo.Stream., @"D\Xbook2.xlsx");
    }

    public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Hi Yohann**. Thanks for your answer. Solved. Do you think I should put **Book2.xlsx** file to the **Resource folder** or **Project folder**? I mean which one is better?

Comment: Please look at this picture in order to understand what my question is  https://prnt.sc/q1oxck

Comment: Generally speaking, the resource file is mainly something other than the program code file, such as pictures and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the directory tree, I'm assuming that your project path ends like this

```
 SolutionFolder\ProjectFolder\bin\Debug
```

In that case you will need to go backwards 2 steps, This would need something like this

```
 string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
            desktopPath += "\\" + @"\Book1.xlsx";


            string fileSource = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.Combine(new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName).DirectoryName, ""), @"..\..\Book1.xlsx"));


            System.IO.File.Copy(fileSource, desktopPath);
```

So if you want to go back again the 3rd step you would change the

```
@"..\..\Book1.xlsx"
```

to

```
@"..\..\..\Book1.xlsx"
```

I hope this helps.